# How does a Reader in Golang automatically iterate in a loop?

Tags: go

I'm reading about how to use CSVs in Golang and came across this code:

```
csvFile, _ := os.Open("people.csv")
reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(csvFile))
var people []Person
for {
    line, error := reader.Read()
    if error == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
    }
    people = append(people, Person{
        Firstname: line[0],
        Lastname:  line[1],
    })
}
```

Located here: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/parse-csv-data-go-programming-language/

What I find confusing here is with the infinite for-loop, each iteration grabs the next line but there's no `lineNum++` type logic being passed into the Reader. How does the reader know which iteration its on? How can I change this? E.g. grab *just* the first line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How does a Reader in Golang automatically iterate in a loop?
>   How does the reader know which iteration its on?

The Read method returns the next record by consuming more data from the underlying io.Reader. The Read method returns io.EOF when there are no more records in the underlying reader.

The application is responsible for calling read in a loop as shown in the example.

The Reader does not need to know the line number to read the next record, but the Reader does maintain a [line counter](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f3f507b2d86bfb38c7e466a465d5b6463cfd4184/src/encoding/csv/reader.go#L147-L148) in its internal state for annotating errors.

If the application needs to know the line number, the application can declare a counter and increment the counter on each read.

> How can I change this? E.g. grab just the first line.

Call Read once:

```
f, err := os.Open("people.csv")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
} 
defer f.Close()

r := csv.NewReader(f)
firstLine, err := r.Read()
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Comment: The reader also maintains an internal pointer to the current *byte index* it's reading, which it uses as it reads to return the next line when requested.

Comment: @Adrian Where is the pointer to the byte index in the source?

Comment: Depends on the reader, and may not be in Go source (it may be behind a syscall), but every reader knows what it's going to return for the next call to `Read`, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: I thought you were referring the [csv Reader](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv#Reader), not the underlying io.Reader. There are io.Readers [that do not maintain a byte index](https://godoc.org/io#PipeReader) (either in Go code or in the os).

Comment: Fair point, but that's an unusual exception. Even for a live stream like a TCP connection, the stream will be buffered, and the reader will maintain a read index within the buffer. And, since the CSV reader uses a `bufio.Reader` internally... it uses a buffer, and maintains a read index within that buffer.